# statsmodels user-defined parameter ordering in simulate()

Tags: python, statsmodels

In statsmodels, how is the element order of input parameter `params` in [VARMAX.simulate](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax.VARMAX.simulate.html) defined?

One would assume the ordering corresponds to what is given by attribute `param_names` of the created object, but this seems *not* to be the case. See examples below.

```py
import statsmodels as statsmodels 
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
endog = pd.DataFrame({"y":[np.nan, np.nan], "y2":[np.nan, np.nan]}, index=[0, 1])
statsmodels.__version__
>>>>>>>>>
'0.11.1'
```

**Example 1**: Two-variable VAR(1) with intercepts and drifts, all parameters fixed to 0 except for  intercept of `y` set to 1. Yields expected results.

```py
params = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
mod1 = sm.tsa.VARMAX(endog, order=(1, 0), trend=[1, 1], trend_offset=0)
print('\n'.join('{} :{}'.format(*k) for k in zip(mod1.param_names, params)))
print(mod1.simulate(params=params, nsimulations=5, initial_state=[0, 0]))

>>>>>>>>>
intercept.y :1
intercept.y2 :0
drift.y :0
drift.y2 :0
L1.y.y :0
L1.y2.y :0
L1.y.y2 :0
L1.y2.y2 :0
sqrt.var.y :0
sqrt.cov.y.y2 :0
sqrt.var.y2 :0

     y   y2
0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  0.0
2  1.0  0.0
3  1.0  0.0
4  1.0  0.0
```

**Example 2**: Same as in Example 1 but now intercept of variable `y` is set to 0 and intercept of variables `y2` is set to 1. Rather than yielding the expected result it seems that the second element in `params` actually controls the drift parameter of `y` rather than the intercept term of `y2`. This contradicts the parameter ordering given by `mod2.param_names`.

```py
params = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
mod2 = sm.tsa.VARMAX(endog, order=(1, 0), trend=[1, 1], trend_offset=0)
print('\n'.join('{} :{}'.format(*k) for k in zip(mod2.param_names, params)))
print(mod2.simulate(params=params, nsimulations=5, initial_state=[0, 0]))

>>>>>>>>>
intercept.y :0
intercept.y2 :1
drift.y :0
drift.y2 :0
L1.y.y :0
L1.y2.y :0
L1.y.y2 :0
L1.y2.y2 :0
sqrt.var.y :0
sqrt.cov.y.y2 :0
sqrt.var.y2 :0

     y   y2
0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  0.0
2  2.0  0.0
3  3.0  0.0
4  4.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Statsmodels in the ordering of the parameter names.

Comment: Thanks! Will report this as an issue in statsmodels github page.

Comment: Indeed, bug it was. Corrected in https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/7017